# German phrase to excuse unnecessary question

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I am looking for a German phrase similar to the expression

> Sorry for the noise.

used in English speaking forums.

I'd like to excuse an inquiry made in business correspondence that turned out to be obsoloete or irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, given the context I would probably write:

> Bitte entschuldigen Sie die überflüssige/unnötige Anfrage.

Answer (score 4):

I would put

> Ich bitte um Entschuldigung für die Störung.

at the end of your apology. A less formal excuse is:

> Ich bedauere die Störung.

Comment: The latter suggestion doesn't really fit the context provided in the question. He isn't trying to recruit survey respondents.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. I will correct my post.

Comment: Im Kontext eines Forums würde ich eher noch die Formulierung *"Entschuldigt die Störung"* oder "*Entschuldigung für die Störung"* wählen. Deine Formulierung klingt doch etwas sehr förmlich.

Comment: @RoyPJ Der Kontext ist aber "business correspondence".

Comment: @RoyPJ: Ja, das klingt immer sehr förmlich, wenn man um Entschuldigung _bittet_. Das ist aber so richtig, da nur der „Geschädigte“ das Verhalten entschuldigen kann. _Entschuldigung für ..._ ist somit eigentlich sehr unhöflich.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich kommt es auf den allgemeinen Ton im "business" an, man könnte immer noch einen Mittelweg gehen mit *"Bitte entschuldigt / entschuldige / entschuldigen Sie die Störung"*. Es geht ja trotz allem um eine Übersetzung für *"Sorry for the noise."*, nicht *"Please excuse me for creating noise"* (o.Ä.).

Comment: Das _bitte entschuldigt ..._ ist auch gut. Wenn du es nicht so förmlich magst, kannst du auch auf _Entschuldigung_ oder _Verzeihung_ verzichten, und stattdessen dein _Bedauern_ ausdrücken (s. o.).

Comment: Ich hatte eingangs auch an so etwas wie *Bitte entschuldigen Sie die Störung.* gedacht. Das wäre aber in der betreffenden Korrespondenz trotz geschäftlichem Kontext irgendwie zu förmich/zu viel. Aber irgendwie fällt mir auch nichts besseres als das ein.